# restriction in second position - index not used - why?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have created the below example and do not understand why the planner does not use index `i2` for the query. As can be seen in `pg_stats`, it understands that column `uniqueIds` contains unique values. it also understands that column `fourOtherIds` contains only 4 different values. Shouldn't a search of index `i2` then be by far the fastest way? Looking for `uniqueIds` in only four different index leaves of `fourOtherIds`? What is wrong with my understanding of how an index works? Why does it think using `i1` makes more sense here, even though it has to filter out 333.333 rows? In my understanding it should use `i2` to find the one row (or few rows, as there is no unique constraint) that has `uniqueIds` 4000 first and then apply `where fourIds = 1` as a filter.

```
create table t (fourIds int, uniqueIds int,fourOtherIds int);
insert into t ( select 1,*,5 from generate_series(1      ,1000000));
insert into t ( select 2,*,6 from generate_series(1000001,2000000));
insert into t ( select 3,*,7 from generate_series(2000001,3000000));
insert into t ( select 4,*,8 from generate_series(3000001,4000000));
create index i1 on t (fourIds);
create index i2 on t (fourOtherIds,uniqueIds);
analyze t;
select n_distinct,attname from pg_stats where tablename = 't';
/* 
n_distinct|attname     |
----------+------------+
       4.0|fourids     |
      -1.0|uniqueids   |
       4.0|fourotherids|
*/
explain analyze select * from t where fourIds = 1 and uniqueIds = 4000;
/*
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Gather  (cost=1000.43..22599.09 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.667..46.818 rows=1 loops=1)                               |
  Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                      |
  Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                     |
  ->  Parallel Index Scan using i1 on t  (cost=0.43..21598.99 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=25.227..39.852 rows=0 loops=3)|
        Index Cond: (fourids = 1)                                                                                         |
        Filter: (uniqueids = 4000)                                                                                        |
        Rows Removed by Filter: 333333                                                                                    |
Planning Time: 0.107 ms                                                                                                   |
Execution Time: 46.859 ms                                                                                                 |
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every conceivable optimization has been implemented. You are looking for a variant of an [index skip scan](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan) AKA a loose index scan.  PostgreSQL does not automatically implement those (yet--people were working on it but I don't know if they still are.  Also, I think I've read that one of the 3rd party extensions/forks, citus maybe, has implemented it).  You can emulate one yourself using a recursive CTE, but that would be quite annoying to do.

Comment: ty - that must be it. I was even able to get it to use `i2` without providing the leading column of the index in the query, but that is slow (600ms vs <1ms) even though theoretically it could be fast using some skip scan variant as you are saying. It was using 100k buffers instead of 5 buffers which it used when adding the leading column of `i2` to the query also. So index full scan or something.